# Mean function in R for data in csv file

Tags: r, mean, summary, sapply

I tried searching the error which I am getting while using "mean" function in R 3.1.2.'

Purpose: Calculate Mean of datasets
Used Functions: sapply, summary to calculate mean as shown below:

1. `sapply(data,mean,na.rm=TRUE)`
2. `summary(data)`

Problem Faced: Now, I am trying to use "mean" function to calculate mean from complete dataset. I used the function like this:

```
> testingnew <-data[complete.cases(data),]
> mean(testingnew)
```

Popped Warning :

```
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(testingnew) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

Que: Can someone please tell me why this warning comes, I tried to remove NA(missing values) using complete.cases.

Comment: What is `class(testingnew)`? I'm guessing a data.frame. Why aren't you using `sapply` as number 1 suggested? You can't take the mean of a data.frame, but you can take the mean of each of the columns of a data.frame with sapply.

Comment: testingnew is just a transformed dataset enholding no NA values. Yes, I am able to calculate mean using sapply but how to use Mean function on say Column1 - Col1.

Answer (score 0):

```
#To Eliminate missing values: # ! = is not
testingnew <- subset(data, !(is.na(data)))  

#Choose a column to calculate the mean:
#Make sure it is numeric or integer
class(testingnew$Col1)  
mean(testingnew$Col1, na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: I used your suggested method, I am receiving NA as mean :)                    > testingnew <- subset(data, !(is.na(data))) 
> mean(testingnew$Ozone)
[1] NA

Comment: I am curious of the class and content of Ozone. Can please you show the result of class(testingnew$Ozone) and head(testingnew$Ozone) ?

Comment: The class is "integer"..still  NA appears as mean

Comment: O/P:                                                                                                                                                    > class(testingnew$Ozone)                                                                                   [1] "integer"                                                                                                                  > head(testingnew$Ozone)                                                                              [1] 41 36 12 18 28 23

Comment: Maybe try: mean(as.numeric(testingnew$Col1), na.rm=TRUE) , if it does not work, I can't see the problem without the dataset.

Comment: @KvasirEnDevenir, I used subset to exclude NAs and use mean.  Here it is:  > data3 <-subset(data, !is.na(Ozone))
> mean(data3$Ozone)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to reproduce this workflow with your own dataset... It seems the only thing missing is referring to individual columns with the mean function, or using sapply as you did before.

Create a dataframe using random values

```
my.df <- data.frame(x1 = rnorm(n = 200), x2 = rnorm(n=200))
```

Spread NA's randomly into the df

```
is.na(my.df) <- matrix(sample(c(TRUE,FALSE), replace= TRUE, size = 400, 
                          prob=c(0.10, 0.90)),
                   ncol = 2)
```

For getting means without using complete cases:

```
mean(my.df$x1, na.rm=TRUE) # mean(my.df[,1], na.rm=TRUE) is equivalent
mean(my.df$x2, na.rm=TRUE) # mean(my.df[,2], na.rm=TRUE) is equivalent
```

Complete-case approach (if this is what you really need):

```
my.df.complete <- my.df[complete.cases(my.df),]
```

Get means for both columns

```
sapply(X = my.df.complete, FUN = mean)
```

Get mean from individual columns

```
mean(my.df.complete$x1)
mean(my.df.complete$x2)
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the way to calculate the mean. However, the same Warning Message persists.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a subset helped:

```
data3 <-subset(data, !is.na(Ozone))
mean(data3$Ozone)
```